# Removed my vimrc but vim still starts in nocp mode

Tags: vimrc

According to `:h compatible`:

> (...) when a |vimrc| or |gvimrc| file exists,
>   Vim will use the Vim defaults, otherwise it will use the Vi defaults.

But when I try:

```
$ mv ~/.vimrc vimrc
$ vim -c 'set cp?'
```

Vim tells me:

```
nocompatible
```

If I force it by:

```
$ vim -u NONE -c 'set cp?'
```

Vim correctly answers me with

```
compatible
```

I'm confident I have no `~/.gvimrc`, what could cause this vim behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to DJ McMayhem pointing me in the right direction I found that Linux distros meddle with the `nocompatible` behaviour of `vim`.  Since I cannot expect that everyone here know `unix` jargon, where I use `$` I'm working as a normal user and where I use `#` i do commands as the superuser (`root`).

### 1. Vim ignores `/etc/vimrc` for the purpose of setting `nocompatible`

With `:scriptnames` I found `vim` loads the `/etc/vimrc` script.  I then removed both `vimrc` scripts and tested:

```
$ mv ~/.vimrc ~/vimrc.bak
# mv /etc/vimrc /etc/vimrc.bak
$ vim -c 'set cp?'
```

And got

```
compatible
```

That is what we expected, but I tested further.  I have created a `/etc/vimrc` containing `set ff=unix` (completely unrelated from `nocp`) and checked:

```
# echo set ff=unix > /etc/vimrc
$ vim -c 'set cp?'
```

And surprisingly I got:

```
compatible
```

Moreover `:scriptnames` clearly indicated:

```
1: /etc/vimrc
```

---

Adding a `~/.vimrc` on the other hand triggers `nocompatible` correctly:

```
$ echo set ff=unix > ~/.vimrc
$ vim -c 'set cp?'
nocompatible
```

Vim did not understood the existence of `/etc/vimrc` as a `vimrc` file for the purpose of setting `nocompatible`, but it did understood the existence of `~/.vimrc`.  In `unix` philosophy that is correct, since it is a multi-user system by default the existence of a global configuration file shall never make a difference for a user.

### 2. `/etc/vimrc` is created by the package manager on *nix systems

The suspicion about the strange behaviour I got in the question falls on the contents of the original `/etc/vimrc` file (currently backed up as `/etc/vimrc.bak`).  Looking through it I found this line:

```
runtime! archlinux.vim
```

I'm running `vim` on `archlinux` therefore it makes some sense.  I found the file at `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/archlinux.vim` and it does contain:

```
set nocompatible
```

as the first non-comment line!  That explains it all.

### Conclusion

I then checked on a `centos` and a `debian` machines.  It turns out that in one way or another (by using `runtime` or directly in `/etc/vimrc`) they all perform:

```
set nocompatible
```

explicitly, inside the configuration that is maintained by the package manager (`yum`, `apt`, `pacman`).  That is *bad* practice!

Moral of the story:  Your Linux distro is likely meddling in the global `vim` configuration files.  Be sure to check these files before arguing about strange behaviour of `vim`.

Answer (score 5):

I just tried it, and I think I know what causes this. When I delete my vimrc, start vim, and run `:scriptnames` it says a default vimrc is loaded from

```
1: C:\Program Files (x86)\vim\_vimrc
```

(although this probably depends on what operating system you're on). If you delete this file, vim will start in compatible mode. You can find out where this file is by running `:scriptnames`, and it should be the first result.

Comment: Thanks, your answer pointed me into the right direction.  And `:scriptnames` helped too.  But on a *nix system there appears to be some extra behaviour changes.  I'll add a self answer in a moment.